# datagrid and minHeight property

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface

I'm stumped on what I assume must be a trivial problem.  I've got a panel, which contains a datagrid (expected to fill up the majority of the realestate fluidly), and a handful of buttons and text fields pinned to the bottom edge of the panel.  Its a classic datagrid+search combo.  What I'm stuck on, is that while the datagrid will grow into large 'viewport' just fine, after I shrink down to about 600 pixels or so, the height of the datagrid stops shrinking, pushing the bottom-pinned content off-screen.  I've played with various settings of minHeight, and while larger settings work (also, curiously, overlaying the bottom-pinned stuff where it belongs, instead of off-screen). the smaller settings are apparently ignored or overwritten for some reason.

It seems as if there must be another setting of some sort that I need to make, but I've been messing with this now for hours, and I'm just hoping one of you knows exactly what the issue is.  My problem now is that I don't know what else to try!

Here's a few screenshots, first the design preview, second, the browser rendering.  You can see how the bottom row of buttons gets cut off, and, if I shrink the window even more, I'll cut off parts of the datagrid as well.

[image: The 'design' preview]
[image: the browser rendering]

Thanks!

EDIT:  here's code to my test app, where all the behavior is what it should be...and the hierarchy exactly mimics whats going on in my test app (copy/pasted directly from) .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="100%">


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]private var _data:ArrayCollection;
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>




<s:Group  width="100%" height="100%">   

    <s:BorderContainer  width="100%" height="100%"
                        backgroundColor="silver"
                        cornerRadius="8"
                        borderStyle="inset" borderWeight="1"
                        >

        <!--Main application viewstack-->
        <mx:ViewStack  width="100%" height="100%" >



            <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%">

                <!--sub-application viewstack-->
                <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">

                    <mx:ViewStack id="vs" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0"  >


                        <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%">
                            <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">



                                <s:Panel 
                                    minHeight="170"
                                    title="Order Entry—Customer    [Search for existing contacts...]" height="100%" width="100%">

                                    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
                                        <s:Group clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

                                            <mx:DataGrid 
                                                id="dgSelect" 
                                                dataProvider="{_data}" 
                                                sortableColumns="false" resizableColumns="true"  draggableColumns="false"
                                                doubleClickEnabled="true" 
                                                allowMultipleSelection="false" 
                                                minHeight="68"
                                                top="4" bottom="70" left="4" right="4">
                                                <mx:columns>
                                                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Last Name" dataField="LName" width="100" />
                                                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="First Name" dataField="FName"  width="100" />
                                                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Address" dataField="Address1"  width="250" />
                                                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="City" dataField="City"  width="100" />
                                                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="State" dataField="State" width="50" />
                                                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Zip" dataField="Zip"  width="50" />
                                                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Email" dataField="EMail" />
                                                </mx:columns>
                                            </mx:DataGrid>

                                            <s:Group bottom="40" left="4" width="100%" height="21">
                                                <s:Label text="Last"  width="41" height="22" verticalAlign="middle"/>
                                                <s:TextInput id="txtSearchLast" maxChars="9"  width="100" left="41"/>

                                                <s:Label text="First"  width="36" verticalAlign="middle" left="185" height="21"/>
                                                <s:TextInput id="txtSearchFirst" maxChars="9" width="100" left="220"/>

                                                <s:Label id="lblSearchError" color="#FF0000" fontSize="10" left="336" right="158"/>
                                                <mx:Spacer width="100%"/>
                                                <s:Button id="btnSearchSelect" label="Select"  right="80"/>
                                                <s:Button id="btnSearchEdit"   label="Edit"    right="4"/>

                                            </s:Group>




                                            <s:Group bottom="10" height="21">
                                                <s:layout >
                                                    <s:HorizontalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10"/>
                                                </s:layout>

                                                <mx:Button id="btnCancel"  label="Cancel" />    
                                                <mx:Spacer/>
                                                <mx:Button id="btnStartOver"  label="Start Over" />
                                                <mx:Spacer/>
                                                <mx:Button id="btnExpressContact"  label="Express Contact"/>
                                                <mx:Button id="btnExpressCart" label="Ω" />
                                                <mx:Spacer/>
                                                <mx:Button  id="btnCustomerNew"   label="New Customer"      />  
                                                <mx:Spacer/>                    
                                                <mx:Button id="btnNext"   label="Next"     />

                                            </s:Group>

                                        </s:Group>
                                    </s:Scroller>


                                </s:Panel>
                            </s:Group>
                        </s:NavigatorContent> 

                    </mx:ViewStack> 
                </s:Group>
            </s:NavigatorContent> 

        </mx:ViewStack>





    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:Group>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, a little peace of code will help.
How do you implement your viewport? Where you are setting your scroller. What is the layoutproperty and so one.

As i understand, you are writing a application with flex4 and spark components, right?

You have to define a scroller (viewport) in your application for scrollbars. Spark components do not have automatic scrollbars like the halo components.

One of the multiple possibilities are to define a skin for the application. In this skin, code an scroller around the content group. After this, set the hight and width properties to 100%.

maybe this will help without code

see you
Frank

Comment: by viewport, I mean only the part of the browser window you're looking through.  Sorry to confuse.

Comment: as far as code goes, I'll try to recreate in a setting that isn't completely slathered in other details, just limiting to the ui bits, without all the database search related code.

Comment: no dice on code.  I copied out my panel into a new application, removed the ui events from the buttons, datagrid, etc, and the durned thing works exactly the way I think it should.  There's some something else in the way I've got things nested before the panel (a viewstack component, and some other groups) that must be causing the issue.

Comment: can be. Be careful with mixing halos and sparks. Often i had exactly the same problem. When your application is a mx and the datagrid too, you have no trouble with scrollbars. But if you nasted a mx datagrid into an spark group, the trouble starts. In this case you have to define viewports or writing a scroller around the group.

Comment: I've just completed rebuilding my test app, with all the groups and datagrids and everything.  The only thing I left out was logic, and, the other viewstack views.  The hierarchy looks like this...s:Application -> s:Group -> s:BorderContainer -> mx:ViewStack -> s:NavigatorContent -> s:Group -> mx:ViewStack -> s:NavigatorContent -> s:Group -> s:Panel -> s:Scroller -> s:Group -> [[ which finally contains my datagrid, buttons, etc]] ........ that one works flawlessly too.   How can I troubleshoot this, to find where the misbehavior is coming from?

Comment: Hi, did your original app also the scroller tag around the group who contain the datagrid? i don't belive, the misbehavior comes from logic or viewstack. paste your original code peace for peace in your testapp and try to find out, which peace is guilty

Comment: yeah, its EXACTLY the same in my test app...all I took out were the event pieces...and, pasting the same code from the test app, back into the real app, I get the same issue.  So I know the problem isn't the panel itself, its upstream somewhere. I'll do my best to try it piece-meal.

Comment: NOTE:: code added above...not that its terribly useful, since it works! ......also, about the scroller.  I don't actually WANT a scroller, it was just something I tried as a 'make-it-work' idea.  I'm not overly concerned about the scroller, I just want to learn why the design I've provided isn't being followed.  I'm sure its my fault, but, I still need to learn what I've done.

Comment: i think it makes no sense to guess, where this issue is, without any peace of code, where the issue happens. i think, the dg will not shrink to the minHeight without scrollbars. so far i understand your problem, why your buttons are cutting instead shrinking the dg to minheight. The different in you screenshot are with and without data

Comment: the one without data behaves the same when plugged in that way with my real app...its not a data dependant issue.  The code for the sample app is included in the main post now.

Comment: since I've proved that what I'm trying to do is at least possible, I think I'm now stuck with trying to find a way to debug the real app.  Also, Frank, just to be sure I say it, I appreciate your help in this matter.  Any 'sharpness' you might be hearing from me is not directed at you, but is just frustration in general.

Comment: I've now removed all code from the s:Panel, its just empty, and it displays the same behavior.  I'll keep removing bits, like Frank said, until I get to SOMETHING that change the end behavior.  Thanks for listening while I take notes for the sake of historicity :D

Comment: replaced the entire secondary viewstack with the same empty panel.  Same behavior.  Same also, for replacing the primary viewstack..I'm getting closer..!

Comment: Yanked out durn near everything, all the way down to the main app, and finally, I got the panel to start behaving!  Now, to revert to my old svn, and start trimming more judiciously.  I have a suspicion about a background image on that border container...

Comment: culprit is NOT the image...back to the drawing board...but at least I'm moving forward!

Comment: alright!  I've found the issue!  The problem turned out to be an s:Group thats a sibling of the main viewstack.  I use bindings on an initComplete variable to hide/show the two different members...the init group shows a barber pole and initialization status', and then, when we've completed our setup, then I flip the bit, and hide the initGroup, and show the viewstack.   .... Unfortunately, I'd not also set the IncludeInLayout property, so, even though the initGroup was hidden, it was still constraining the layout.   Thanks for listening!